# Funcion en segundo plano en python

Tags: python, hilos

mi problema es que tengo una funcion que con while consulta un websocket y deberia quedar corriendo esa funcion mientras el resto del script sigu, el resto de las funciones trabajando en base a los datos que salen de la anterior y se van actualizando todo el tiempo, desde ya gracias

funcion.py

```
def fun():
    while True:
      d= "algo"
      return d
```

programa.py

```
for funcion import fun
funci = fun()
while True:
    print "otro algo",funci
```

lo que me interesa es que lo que devuelve sea algo como:

> otro algo algo

Comment: debes proveer un [mcve]

Comment: Si tu usas un return el bucle termina, asi que por ejemplo funcion.py es equivalente a `def fun(): return "algo"`. Asi que la idea no es retornar la funcion sino compartir datos entre hilos y para ello debes usar una cola(Queue) https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html, en el ultima parte de este enlace hay un ejemplo de lo que deseas